# Service "ntopng" won't start

Tags: 15.04, systemd

I have installed *[ntopng - High-Speed Web-based Traffic Analysis and Flow Collection Tool](http://www.ntop.org/products/traffic-analysis/ntop/)*

The service won't start:

```
% sudo systemctl start ntopng.service
Job for ntopng.service failed. See "systemctl status ntopng.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

---

*Details*

```
% systemctl status ntopng.service
● ntopng.service - ntopng - High-Speed Web-based Traffic Analysis and Flow Collection Tool
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntopng.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mi 2015-07-01 19:32:15 CEST; 9s ago
  Process: 11924 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c   . /etc/default/ntopng;   INTERFACES_ARG="";   if [ -n "$INTERFACES" ]; then    for i in $INTERFACES; do     INTERFACES_ARG="$INTERFACES_ARG -i $i";    done;   fi;   exec /usr/sbin/ntopng --daemon --pid /var/tmp/ntopng.pid -w $HTTP_PORT $INTERFACES_ARG $ADD_ARGS (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)

Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: Failed to start ntopng - High-Speed Web-based Traffic Analysis and Flow Collection Tool.
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: Unit ntopng.service entered failed state.
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: ntopng.service failed.
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: ntopng.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for ntopng.service
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: Failed to start ntopng - High-Speed Web-based Traffic Analysis and Flow Collection Tool.
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: Unit ntopng.service entered failed state.
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: ntopng.service failed.
```

and

```
% journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ntopng.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm systemd[1]: Unit ntopng.service entered failed state.
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm systemd[1]: ntopng.service failed.
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm audit[1]: <audit-1130> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=ntopng comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm systemd[1]: ntopng.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm audit[1]: <audit-1130> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=ntopng comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=ntopng comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm systemd[1]: Starting ntopng - High-Speed Web-based Traffic Analysis and Flow Collection Tool...
-- Subject: Unit ntopng.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ntopng.service has begun starting up.
Jul 01 19:32:14 sturm audit[11924]: <audit-1701> auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 pid=11924 comm="ntopng" exe="/usr/sbin/ntopng" sig=6
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: ntopng.service: control process exited, code=dumped status=6
Jul 01 19:32:15 sturm systemd[1]: Failed to start ntopng - High-Speed Web-based Traffic Analysis and Flow Collection Tool.
-- Subject: Unit ntopng.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

How should I proceed?

---

*OS info*

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

*Package info*

```
% apt-cache policy ntopng
ntopng:
  Installed: 1.2.1+dfsg1-1.1
  Candidate: 1.2.1+dfsg1-1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.1+dfsg1-1.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Have you tried following http://xmodulo.com/set-web-based-network-traffic-monitoring-linux.html tutorial for the installation?

Comment: @DevRobot No, I have installed the Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `/etc/ntopng.conf`

I had same issue, I update the `-i` parameter with the server interfaces.
start the service.